# jung ObservableCachingLayout vs staticLayout

Tags: layout, graph, jung

i m trying to get the x and y cordinate from the layout but when geting the layout from a VisualizationViewer the returned type **is not** ***staticLayout*** but ***ObservableCachingLayout*** (of course it couldn't be casted to static).
Is there a way to get the staticlayout from a VisualizationViewer ?
Or a way to get the x and y from the viz ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the x and y coordinate from the `Layout`, you call `layout.transform(vertex)`.  (A `Layout` is a `Transformer` from vertices to `Point` objects.)

`StaticLayout` is an instance of `Layout` that allows the user to easily specify the coordinates of each vertex; it's intended for the case in which you already have coordinates and don't need an algorithm to determine them.

Comment: I suggest the `StaticLayout` class name shall be changed to `FixedLayout` to avoid the confusion due to the use of "static" keyword :)